unexpected additional scopes requested during google oauth flow
I added google oauth for login in a mobile app im working on. In the the google cloud console as well as in the client side app, the only scope I have is "email". Until now it worked fine and the consent screen included just the the email scope. But suddenly, I started seeing additional scopes being requested including "profile" and "openid". The exact message I get during the signin flow is:
<app-name> wants additional access to your Google Account

and lists these 3:
1.  See your personal info, including any personal info you've made publicly available 

2.  Associate you with your personal info on Google 

3.  See your primary Google Account email address 

I only need the email address and the only scope i enabled is "email". I could not figure out from where the additional scopes are included. Any one know how I can identify why these scopes are requested? I tried the console.cloud.google.com/ and firebase console but they look correct. I would like to remove the 2 additional scopes, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.



Email is part of sign-in which is profile and opened.   They are added by default often by the library you are using

You are 100% correct, I am using expo-auth-session pkg's google provider and it is using a minimum scope that includes these 3 scope and hasnt changed recently. https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-auth-session/build/providers/Google.js#L39. Its possible that Google consent UI has changed recently and shows the scope + description more prominently which I must have misunderstood! Thanks you so much for the help.

Yes they have been rolling out new consent screen
